# Switches in WixShellExecTarget

Tags: wix, custom-action

from a Wix installer package I am starting one of the installed programs at the end of the setup, according to http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/run_program_after_install.html:

```
<Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#myapplication.exe]" />
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes" />
```

I now need to include a switch ("/X") to start the program with and failed to find out how to do that (adding it to Value disables the start of the program alltogehter) - any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> WixShellExecTarget must be only the path of the executable/document. 
>   There's no support to add arguments. For that, use a "normal" exe custom 
>   action instead of WixShellExec.

> Because a more typical use case is to launch a document (like a 
>   readme.html or .pdf). WixShellExec was designed just for that purpose.

*http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Passing-command-line-arguments-to-an-app-launched-after-setup-td1366362.html*

---

You could replace your custom action with something like:

```
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" 
     Impersonate="yes" 
     FileKey="[Id for File element that was installed]"
     ExeCommand="/X" 
     Return="asyncNoWait" />
```

I guessed on some of the attributes that you'd want, but you could use [the Wix `CustomAction` element reference page](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/customaction.html) for more information.  I think you want custom action type 18 (to run an executable copied during this installation), so [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613741/how-to-run-custom-executable-with-elevated-privileges) should help as well.

Comment: jjj answer is a life saver. I spent two days trying to figure out how to launch an application with command line parameters after the installation. No other technique worked (WixShellExec, etc.), only this one.